# Is "rpm" really tag-worthy?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I saw a wiki description review request today for [rpm](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm).

At present there are 31 questions tagged with on Mechanics.SE and I wonder how useful it is.

As it relates to engine speed, wouldn't [engine-speed](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-speed) be a more appropriate tag to use?

Comment: I reckon engine speed and rpm could happily be synonymised :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think [engine-speed](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-speed) is much more descriptive than [rpm](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm) is and think [rpm](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm) could easily be synonymised under the other. They are both indicating the exact same thing and there doesn't seem to be a lock on either.

Comment: In most cases I tend to agree, since people commonly use RPM to indicate the rotations per minute of the engines crankshaft. However I would not say that engine speed and rpm are the exact same thing. Anything that turns to complete a revolution (end up where it started) can be measured in rpm. For example, the RPM of camshafts is 1/2 the RPM of the crankshaft. Both are pieces of the engine, but the measurement is different.

Comment: @NickG - Something that RPM can also stand for is *Rotations Per Mile* when considering tires. Another reason for me to have engine speed as the go-to here.

Comment: Yeah it would be better all spelled out.